# How to guarantee that a website done in angular works even when accessing it via proxies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, proxy

I have this site where I did a simple feature in angular. The feature consists in selecting a location and add it to a group of locations. Every location has a district, a county and a locality, and I have a select box for each of these, and an add button. When I have all the three selected the button becomes active and I add that location to the group. What happens is that I have those selected boxes linked to an object via `ng-model` and then I add that object to an array with an `add function` and render it with `ng-repeat`. All this works fine in a normal context, no problems at all, but if I access the site via proxy when I try to add the location it crashes and returns to the previous page. In the console the erros show that the location object that should be rendered is undefined but I fail to understand why. I though maybe the proxy was blocking some of the scripts but I inspected with the angular dev tools and all seems to be good in terms of data structure. I have no clue of what's happening or how I should address the problem. If anyone has ever faced this problem and managed to solve it and could give an hint it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you using navigator.geolocation? This method in chrome can only be called by localhost or https. So, check if you site is running as secure or if the proxy allow https requests.

Comment: Danilo, I'm not using any location plugin, only data that comes from the database. The site is accessed via https.

Comment: Your api server is using port 80/443?

Comment: Right now I can't confirm what port it is using but I guess it's a regular web 80... Can confirm that tomorrow. What are you thinking that might be the problem?

Comment: Some proxies only allow traffic through port 80 and 443. If your api is in another port (in my case was 3000), the proxy dont do port redirects and calls from angular fails.